# Windows Explorer folders jumping

Tags: windows-7

Windows Explorer in Windows 7 seems to jump around more than previous versions. The directory forlders seem to want to reposition the directory "just right" in the display. So opening a subfolder can cause a significant shift in the display. Aside from annoying, this has also caused a different directory to be positioned under my cursor and a file or sub-sub-directory to be opened incorrectly. (I'm not talking here about keeping things onscreen).

Any way to slow this down?

Comment: Honestly I always thought this was a feature, not a bug. I've found it to come in handy, but never realized it was inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I had a coworker that experienced this issue. In my research on the issue, it seems to be a problem that will not be fixed with Windows 7, but that will hopefully be fixed with Windows 8.

Workarounds: Installing alternate shell  or utilizing "Total Commander".

Here are some links that also explain the folder expanding issue.

[Forum Post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-expands-folders-inappropriately/50a81b05-da98-4d55-821d-55ffbbd0e998)

[Microsoft Bug Report *lists other workarounds](http://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/621426/bug-when-expanding-folders-in-explorer-server-2008-r2-and-windows-7#)

Answer (score 0):

“dwightrj” on WindowsSevenForums.com suggests right-clicking on a blank area of the Explorer pane at the left, then un-checking `Expand to Current Folder` and `Show All Folders`. It still jumps around a little, but it much less annoying.